# querySelectorAll not returning all elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, web, polymer, components

I am working on a side project in which the HTML file is generated and sent to the front end, where it is being formatted and displayed using Polymer 3 and other technologies.

Long story short, when I call `querySelectorAll`, it does not return, for example, all anchor tags in the `document`:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a");
```

Rather, it only seems to acknowledge the existence of tags if they are direct children of the node upon which `querySelectorAll` is called.  So, if I have:

```
<div>
  <custom-tag1>
    <custom-tag2>
      <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
      <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
      <a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a>
    </custom-tag2>
  </custom-tag2>
</div>
```

I've found I have to first get the `document` object, then the body object, then anything living on the top level of the `body` object (let's say the above div is immediately inside body, for example), etc.

So if I (finally!) get a reference to the body, I can call:

```
theBody.querySelectorAll("a");
```

and it will return an empty list.  I have to do something like this:

```
theBody.querySelectorAll("div")[0].querySelectorAll("custom-tag1")[0].querySelectorAll("custom-tag2")[0].querySelectorAll("a");
```

in order to get a list of the anchor elements!

But, if anchors exist anywhere else, it won't get them.

**Notes:**
Polymer 3 server is running.
The situation may be complicated by the fact that some of the elements (at least those I see in Chrome's debugger) are **shadow roots**.

Thus, sometimes, we end up doing this:

```
someNode.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("a");
```

or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `console.log` in all your `custom-tagX` elements' `ready` methods (and in `onload` in <body>), then you will see why. The result you would see would look something like this ...

```
 body is ready
 custom-tag1 is ready
 custom-tag2 is ready
```

... meaning that when the body is done loading, then your Polymer specific custom elements will load.

So to solve this, you need to send out an event when a specific element has loaded, and let body listen for it with `addEventListener`.

However, this is not how you should think when it comes to Polymer.

Why do you want the `<a>` tags in the first place?

<s>I would instead build a behavior, and add it to `custom-tag2`, and every time you want to do whatever you want with the `<a>` tags in a custom element, just add that behavior to the element.</s>
*(I looked it up, and it's just for Polymer 1)*

I would instead use mixins to share code that does something to the `<a>` tags.

https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#mixins

Answer (score -5):

Yes! As @Jonas Wilms said, it's "[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)".
There is nothing called "[querySelectAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectAll)".

Comment: Yes, sorry - I just fixed that.  Was not the original problem - it's right in my actual code.  It was 3 a.m. when I typed the question and I just forgot to type the "or" - sorry about that.

The problem persists.